# Get confused by for loop with srand

Tags: c++, loops, random, srand

I try to print out all the random number.

And there should be 100000 lines.

but when I count the line, there's only 9000 lines.

I was very confused why there are some missing line.

Hope someone can help me.

```
    srand(114);
    double b=0;
    for(int i = 0;i<1000;i++){
            for(int j =0 ;j<10;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<10;k++){
                    b=double(rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0));
                    cout<<b<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I ran it and redirected the output to a file. 100000 lines.

Comment: if this is windows you can increase the scrollback buffer on the cmd.exe window your program runs in.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you count the lines to get the value 9000?

Below is your exact code with an added counter variable to verify that the loops run 100000 times, so it might be simply a display issue on your console.

https://onlinegdb.com/rkUJLJJXD

Comment: i use std::cin.get(); and copy all the line to clipboard and find out there's only 9000 lines.

Comment: You are copying the lines to the clipboard manually?

Comment: If you are copying the lines manually, it's most likely the display not showing the entirety of your output. As 100000 lines is quite a lot, sometimes the output console will  limit itself and only show to a certain amount. Check the code I linked above. It's your exact code, and it counts to 100000, so your code is not the problem.

Comment: Yes, that is doing it manually. It sounds like it's just your console limiting the output display. Nothing to be worried about.